# Suggestions on RESTful Java Web Services Framework... 

Tags: java, apache, frameworks, rest

I googled some information about web services, it seems like a enterprise level application. I found that RESTful design is very cool idea on this. I find that Apache CXF looks cool, it support RESTful design and Java. It is a good choice for beginner to start writing an application using Apache CXF? or any other framework is suggested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use JAX-RS because IMHO it is the most neutral framework in terms of telling you how REST should be done. I have not used CXF, only Jersey. It is a very solid implementation and comes with a good client side connector, too (client side not part of JAX-RS yet).

Being neutral with regard to 'how to do REST' is important because there is not yet an acknowledged 'best' way to approach certain aspects (e.g. design of hypermedia).

Congrats to going the REST way - you won't regret it.

Jan

Answer (score 8):

I'd go for [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), the RI of [JAX-RS](https://jsr311.dev.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/index.html) (JSR 311), the Java API for RESTful Web Services (i.e. a standard).

Answer (score 2):

The much simpler implementation for a beginner would be spring 3.0 REST support. Spring MVC 3.0 has REST support and is very much simpler compared to Apache CXF.

Comment: Wow... better read the question next time... missed the word web service. Thought about a RESTful architecture style.

Comment: @spa Can you please elaborate on what you are saying or a resource which explains better about them?

Comment: I think @spa was answering my comment, this is not a direct comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Restlet** in another RESTful web framework for Java : http://www.restlet.org/

Comment: It seems not so famous like the Apache CXF and Spring, is there any special features in Restlet?

Comment: You can have a list of the features provided by Restlet : http://www.restlet.org/about/features

Apache CXF and Spring MVC are very good projects. But, unlike Restlet, they are not focused on REST applications.

Comment: Restlet came before JAX-RS so it has it's own architecture. I did see the feature that they added JAX-RS 1.0 integration.

Answer (score 1):

I get started REST with [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/resteasy/freezone/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html/index.html) and get it up in 30 minutes. You can use it as stand-alone lib in your favorite servlet container without all this JBoss stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You should try PlayFramework. Just take a loot at a sample route file and you will know how easy it is to use play to implement RESTFul web app:

```
# ====== Order service =========================
GET /orders Orders.list
GET /orders/{<[0-9]+>id} Orders.show
PUT /orders/{<[0-9]+>id} Order.saveUpdate
POST /orders Orders.saveNew
# ==============================================
```

And corresponding controller methods:

```
public class Orders extends Controller {
   public static void list() {
      List<Order> orders = Order.all();
      render(orders);
   }
   public static void show(long id) {
      Order order = Order.findById(id);
      notFoundIfNull(order);
      render(order);
   }
   public static void saveUpdate(long id, Order update) {
      Order order = Order.findById(id);
      notFoundIfNull(order);
      order.update(update);
      show(id);
   }
   public static void saveNew(Order order) {
      order.save();
      show(order.getId());
   }
}
```

There are some utilities enable you to interact with other Web Services:

```
String url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("v", "1.0");
params.put("q", searchStr);
params.put("key", Play.configuration.get("app.google.key"));
params.put("userip", myIpAddr);
HttpResponse resp = WS.url(url).params(params).get();
return resp.getString();
```